# target id android-8 is not valid. use 'android list targets' to get the target ids

Tags: android, python, kivy, android-sdk-tools

I want to build apk from my python main.py file. I am running this command

```
./build.py --package org.test.testapp --name testapp --version 1.0 --dir testapp debug adb installd
```

I am getting error as

```
Error: Target id 'android-8' is not valid. Use 'android list targets' to get the target ids.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 412, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "./build.py", line 304, in make_package
    make_pythonzip()
  File "./build.py", line 132, in make_pythonzip
    python_files = [x for x in listfiles(d) if select(x)]
  File "./build.py", line 96, in listfiles
    for item in os.listdir(d):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/home/Downloads/python-for-android/src/private/lib/python2.7'
```

Answer (score 1):

It means you didn't followed the requirements / python-for-android installation process. You get this issue because you didn't installed the Android API 8 on your computer.